# CRUD Operations in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing an application in MVC 5 and perform CRUD operations on it.

I have successfully added Northwind database as an Entity Data Model and taking Customer in the Model. Now with the help of Scaffolding I generated the CustomersController.

When I create a new record in a Customer Table. There is no problem.

But when I click on that new record, Edit, Details and Delete are not working. After clicking any of these:

[image]

The following page occurs:

[image]

My Controller Code:

```
namespace MvcNorthwindSample.Controllers
{

    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        private NORTHWNDEntities db = new NORTHWNDEntities();

        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Customers.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Customers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Customers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Customers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Address,City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Fax")] Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Customers.Add(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Customers/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // POST: Customers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CustomerID,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Address,City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Fax")] Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // GET: Customers/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(customer);
        }

        // POST: Customers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
            db.Customers.Remove(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

My  View Part:

[image]

My Create Code Result view while debugging:

[image]

Comment: It looks like there's a space character (`%20`) after the id in your URL. Is that intentional?

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for replying. I do not insert space character anywhere.

Comment: Well, it's getting added somewhere. Show us your relevant code (controller and view). We can't fix your problem if you don't give us any information.

Comment: @Yasser I have already mentioned that I generated my controller through scaffolding using Entity Framework with Views

Comment: @NimitJoshi would you mind sharing them ?

Comment: @NimitJoshi looks like it's a problem in your routes

Comment: Please show us the part of your view where the `Edit` links are being added. Your `Edit` action will throw an `HttpNotFound` if the provided ID doesn't locate a valid item, and I'm pretty sure `1994 ` (with a space at the end) will not locate a valid item.

Comment: Thank you. Have you tried deleting the `%20` from the end of the URL (in your browser) to see what happend? Does this occur for all customers, or just certain ones?

Comment: @JLRishe Yes sir, When i am removing the %20, it is working fine. No sir, it occurs only to them which are added from the Create New procedure.

Comment: Follow the Blog for MVC Crud Operation with Interfaces and Repository Pattern with ADO.Net
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/MVC-Crud-Operation-with-Interfaces-and-Repository-Pattern-with-ADONet

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: After you posted your controller:

```
Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
if (customer == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

Are you sure that you have a customer with an `id` of 1994?  If not, your logic would return `HttpNotFound()`.

In the screenshot you posted, I can read `HTTP 404` error message and the requested URL was `/Customer/Edit/1994`.

So for that I assume you must be have the following controller/action:

```
public class CustomerController
{
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now the most common mistake most people make (including me) is properly passing `id` in the URL.  You have `id` specified as an optional parameter in your route pattern:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

So if you don't want to use `id` you could pass something else as a [key name in the the query component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4), e.g., `/Customer/Edit?year=1994`.

Comment: The new record is inserted successfully in the Customer table. Please notice that the Edit, Details and Delete are working fine for the records which are preadded in the table. These are not working only for the newly inserted record.

Comment: When I am removing the %20, the link is working fine for the record.

Comment: `%20` stands for a space. Debug through your code and check why this space is getting added in your link

Comment: Please check out the code. I have pasted a screenshot. You can easilt check out that there is a space in the ID. But I did not edit my code. Would you please tell me where can i edit this?

Comment: Sir there is a problem in the Customers Table of Northwind database which is downloaded. The space is added on the Customer ID column as a default. I do not know why this is happening. But thanks for the help. I changed the table and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a 404 Error.

It is looking in the Controller `Customers` for an `Edit` action.

Also pointed out in the comments the Id 1994 has a encoded space character following it.  If the id is suppose to be strings, you can change the parameter to type `string` instead of `int`

```
public class CustomersController
{
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is generated automatically from the Scaffolding. When I changed this the links are not working for all records and in the case of not editing the links are not working only for those records which are added from the create new procedure. These links are working fine for the rest records.

Comment: Follow the Blog for MVC Crud Operation with Interfaces and Repository Pattern with ADO.Net
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/MVC-Crud-Operation-with-Interfaces-and-Repository-Pattern-with-ADONet

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I changed the table at last. There is a problem on the table named Customers of the Northwind database. I download database backup file. The Customer ID column is adding a space as a default with the inserted value.

Comment: Follow the Blog for MVC Crud Operation with Interfaces and Repository Pattern with ADO.Net
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/MVC-Crud-Operation-with-Interfaces-and-Repository-Pattern-with-ADONet

Answer (score 0):

First create your models and Dbcontext.

```
public class TaskManagerContext : DbContext
{
    public TaskManagerContext()
        : base("TaskManagerDB")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Then allow migrations and update the database from the PM. Create a folder Repositories with a BaseRepo that the rest must inherit.

```
public class BaseRepository<T> where T:BaseModel, new()
{
    protected TaskManagerContext context;
    protected DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        this.context = new TaskManagerContext();
        this.dbSet = this.context.Set<T>();
    }

    public void Insert(T item)
    {
        this.dbSet.Add(item);
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        this.context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        this.dbSet.Remove(this.dbSet.Find(id));
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return this.dbSet;
    }
}
```

like this:

```
public class UsersRepository : BaseRepository<User>
{
    public UsersRepository()
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you create the controllers in which you use the methods from the repos.

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Users/
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        users = new UsersRepository().GetAll().ToList();
        return View(users);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        User user = new UsersRepository().GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
        return View(user);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(User user)
    {
        UsersRepository repo = new UsersRepository();
        repo.Update(user);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        UsersRepository repo = new UsersRepository();
        repo.Delete(id);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        User u = new User();
        return View(u);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        UsersRepository repo = new UsersRepository();
        repo.Insert(user);

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
}
```

The actions for the TaskContr are simillar exept the List in which you connect the 2 models by ID:

```
public ActionResult List(int? id)
    {
        TasksRepository repo = new TasksRepository();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        tasks = repo.GetAll().Where(t => t.UserID == id).ToList();
        return View(tasks);
    }
```

Don't forget to generate views(on the Get methods) and change the List view for the Users:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "List", "Tasks", new { id=item.ID }, null) |
```

That way when clicking Details you can see the tasks for that user.

Comment: Follow the Blog for MVC Crud Operation with Interfaces and Repository Pattern with ADO.Net
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/MVC-Crud-Operation-with-Interfaces-and-Repository-Pattern-with-ADONet

Answer (score 0):

```java
  public ActionResult Index()
        {

            using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
            {

                var intern = from m in db.Interns 
                             select m;


                return View(intern.ToList());
            }

           /* using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
            {
                var interns = db.Interns
                     .Include(s => s.InternID)
                     .Select(s => new Intern
                     {
                     InternID = s.InternID,
                     lname = s.lname,
                     fname = s.fname 
                     });
                return View(interns);
             }
             */
        }

        // GET: CRUD/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
            {
                return View(db.Interns.Where(x => x.InternID == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

        // GET: CRUD/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: CRUD/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Intern intern)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
                {
                    db.Interns.Add(intern);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CRUD/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
            {
                return View(db.Interns.Where(x => x.InternID == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

        // POST: CRUD/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id,Intern intern)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
                {
                    db.Entry(intern).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: CRUD/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
            {
                return View(db.Interns.Where(x => x.InternID == id).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

        // POST: CRUD/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here
                using (DevExam db = new DevExam())
                {
                    Intern intern = db.Interns.Where(x => x.InternID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    db.Interns.Remove(intern);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: <tr style="background-color: #EDE6E4 ; color: #000000; 
               font-family: 'Century Gothic', Times, serif; font-size: small; 
               border-style: dotted; border-width: medium; border-color: #000000">
        <th>
            <label for="fname" class="control-label">First Name</label>     
        </th>  <th>
            <label class="control-label">Action</label>
        </th>

Comment: Follow the Blog for MVC Crud Operation with Interfaces and Repository Pattern with ADO.Net
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/MVC-Crud-Operation-with-Interfaces-and-Repository-Pattern-with-ADONet

Answer (score 0):

```
    create table tblemployee(
    EmpId int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    EmpName varchar(100),
    PhoneNumber varchar(10),
    Country int,
    State int,
    maritalstetus varchar(50),
    isvoting varchar(50),
    dob datetime,
    doj datetime
    primary key (EmpId)
    )
    
    
    create table tblCountry(
    Id int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(100),
    
    primary key (Id)
    )
    
    insert into tblCountry(Name) values ('India')
    insert into tblCountry(Name) values ('US')
    insert into tblCountry(Name) values ('UK')
    
    
    
    
    
    create table tblstate(
    Id int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    Name varchar(100),
    countryId int,
    primary key (Id)
    )
    
    
    insert into tblstate(Name ,countryId) values ('Delhi',1)
    insert into tblstate(Name , countryId) values ('Bihar' ,1)
    insert into tblstate(Name , countryId) values ('Up',1)
    
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace webTest.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int State { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool MarritalStatus { get; set; }

        public bool IsVoting { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DOJ { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using webTest.Models;

namespace webTest.Controllers
{
    public class EmpController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Emp
        public static string constr = "Data Source=DIVYANSHU;Initial Catalog=EmployeeData;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
        public ActionResult ViewList()
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sqlquery = "select * from tblEmployee";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Employee emp = new Employee()
                    {
                        id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Empid"].ToString().Trim()),
                        Name = dr["EmpName"].ToString(),
                        PhoneNumber = dr["PhoneNumber"].ToString(),
                        Country = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Country"].ToString().Trim()),
                        State = Convert.ToInt32(dr["State"].ToString().Trim()),
                        MarritalStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["maritalstetus"].ToString().Trim()),
                        IsVoting = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isvoting"]),
                        DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dob"].ToString().Trim()),
                        DOJ = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["doj"].ToString().Trim()),
                    };
                    employees.Add(emp);
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return View(employees);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From tblCountry", constr);
            DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
            _da.Fill(_dt);
            ViewBag.Country = ToSelectList(_dt, "Id", "Name");
            _da.Dispose();
            SqlDataAdapter _da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From tblState", constr);
            DataTable _dt1 = new DataTable();
            _da1.Fill(_dt1);
            ViewBag.State = ToSelectList(_dt1, "Id", "Name");
            _da1.Dispose();
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            return View(emp);
        }
        public SelectList ToSelectList(DataTable table, string valueField, string textField)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = row[textField].ToString(),
                    Value = row[valueField].ToString()
                });
            }

            return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee empmodel)
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sqlquery = "insert into tblEmployee(EmpName,PhoneNumber,Country,State,maritalstetus,isvoting,dob,doj) values('" + empmodel.Name + "','" + empmodel.PhoneNumber + "'," + empmodel.Country + "," + empmodel.State + ",'" + empmodel.MarritalStatus + "','" + empmodel.IsVoting + "','" + empmodel.DOB + "','" + empmodel.DOJ + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                employees = listEmployee();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return View("ViewList", employees);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter _da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From tblCountry", constr);
                DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
                _da.Fill(_dt);
                ViewBag.Country = ToSelectList(_dt, "Id", "Name");
                _da.Dispose();
                SqlDataAdapter _da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From tblState", constr);
                DataTable _dt1 = new DataTable();
                _da1.Fill(_dt1);
                ViewBag.State = ToSelectList(_dt1, "Id", "Name");
                _da1.Dispose();
                conn.Open();
                string sqlquery = "select * from tblemployee where empid=" + id + "";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    emp = new Employee()
                    {
                        id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Empid"].ToString().Trim()),
                        Name = dr["EmpName"].ToString(),
                        PhoneNumber = dr["PhoneNumber"].ToString(),
                        Country = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Country"].ToString().Trim()),
                        State = Convert.ToInt32(dr["State"].ToString().Trim()),
                        MarritalStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["maritalstetus"].ToString().Trim()),
                        IsVoting = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isvoting"]),
                        DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dob"].ToString().Trim()),
                        DOJ = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["doj"].ToString().Trim()),
                    };

                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return View(emp);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee empmodel)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sqlquery = "update tblEmployee set EmpName='" + empmodel.Name + "',PhoneNumber='" + empmodel.PhoneNumber + "',Country=" + empmodel.Country + ",State=" + empmodel.State + ",maritalstetus='" + empmodel.MarritalStatus + "',isvoting='" + empmodel.IsVoting + "',dob='" + empmodel.DOB + "',doj='" + empmodel.DOJ + "' where empid=" + empmodel.id + "";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            List<Employee> list = listEmployee();
            return View("ViewList", list);
        }
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sqlquery = "Delete from tblEmployee where empid=" + id + "";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            List<Employee> list = listEmployee();
            return View("ViewList", list);
        }

        public List<Employee> listEmployee()
        {
            List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
            conn.Open();
            string sqlquery = "select * from tblEmployee";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee()
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Empid"].ToString().Trim()),
                    Name = dr["EmpName"].ToString(),
                    PhoneNumber = dr["PhoneNumber"].ToString(),
                    Country = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Country"].ToString().Trim()),
                    State = Convert.ToInt32(dr["State"].ToString().Trim()),
                    MarritalStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["maritalstetus"].ToString().Trim()),
                    IsVoting = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["isvoting"]),
                    DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["dob"].ToString().Trim()),
                    DOJ = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["doj"].ToString().Trim()),
                };
                employees.Add(emp);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return employees;
        }
    }
}

    //in Edit view and in create view replace edit for to 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, ViewBag.Country as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.State, ViewBag.State as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).